# How to reduce video processing time on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, video, video-processing, metal

I am currently using AVComposition and CIFilter for apply filter and AVExportSession to export that video but this is taking to much time like 30 seconds for processing 45 seconds video.

I have also tried to used [MtalPetal](https://github.com/MetalPetal/MetalPetal) with [SDAVAssetExportSession](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession) but still its taking time.

I have also tried GPUImage example but still that is taking time.

Video resolution : 480*480

Note : In my application i can't apply filter at the time of recording.

Can anyone suggest me how to reduce video processing time on iOS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can actually record a video, with a filter active and save it to file as you record, this means there is 0 exporting time.

You will need to use:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput
```

This provides a delegate method for:

```
captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!)
```

Basically, you convert the `CMSampleBuffer` into a CIImage, apply the filter, back to a `CMSampleBuffer`, and save.

Its a difficult API and I would suggest looking at:

[Rosy Writer Swift](https://github.com/ooper-shlab/RosyWriter2.1-Swift)

This gives an idea on how to setup the correct queues for getting the video frames out in order as well as the audio and then passing them through a filter before exporting them on the fly to a video file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the application i am working, in that user have to record video and after that he/she apply filter. Do you have suggestion for that ?

Comment: why would you not allow them to pick the filter as they look like snapchat, then record with the filter on

Comment: The only solution you have then is using the SDAVAssetExportSession and tweaking the settings, using a 1mb bitrate you can reduce it a fair bit in size, especially at 480x